# Menu Drop Down show in column, CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I've a dropdown menu with multiple levels, on a category ("Elaborati")   i've a list of element but is very long to show.. I would like to show as a group or list box items in multiple columns

HTML:

```
        <ul    class="sf-menu sf-navbar" >
            <li>

                <a href="#">Pollo</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Prime lavorazioni</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Bustoni</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Novelli</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Rosticceria</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Seconde lavorazioni</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Petto</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Busto disossato</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Busto alla diavola</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Busto senza petto</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Coscioto</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ali</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Coscia</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Anche</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Polpa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fegati</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Duroni</a></li> 
                         </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Terze lavorazioni</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Busto disossato ripieno</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Rollè</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Tacchino</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Prime lavorazioni</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Busto</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Seconde lavorazioni</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Cosce</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fusi</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Anchi</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Colli</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fesa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Spezzatino</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ossobuco</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Terze lavorazioni</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Rollè</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Panati</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Cordon bleu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spinacine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Petto di pollo panato</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bocconcini</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Corrinboca</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ciquito</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pepite dorate</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#">Coti</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Wrustel di pollo e tacchino</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#">Elaborati</a>
                <ul >
                    <li><a href="#">Alette condite paprica/mais</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bastoncini</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BonRoll classico</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bonroll spinaci</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cannoli</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cipollate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fagottini</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Girelle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hamburger</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hamburguer doppi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hamburger golosi </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hamburger pancetta</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Panzerotti</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pollo ripieno</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rollè di pollo ripieni </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rollè di tacchino ripieni</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rollini</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rotollini</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spiedini</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spiedoni</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stigliole tradizionali</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stigliole palermitane</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Straccetti</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tartufelli</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tortini</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tramezini</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tricolori</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">*Ti piacciono le Stigliole senza uova o preferisci altre spezie sulle Alette?
Comunicaci i tuoi desideri e cercheremo di realizzarli!
</a></li>                                                         
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#">Surgelati</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Merluzzo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Platessa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Polpo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spada</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Calamari</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kebap</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Carrè di agnello</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Patate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Minestrone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Piselli</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spinaci</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Insalata russa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Anelli di cipolla</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Panelle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Broccoli</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cavolfiori</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Carote</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li> 
              <li>
                <a href="#">Suino</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Spalla</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pancettone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lombo Bologna</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Filone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pancetta</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Coppa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Zampetti</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Puntine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fegato</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lardo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rete</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>  
              <li>
                <a href="#">Equino</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Fettinescelte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Noce</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fesotto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Controfileto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Scamone</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li> 
                         <li>
                <a href="#">Vitello</a>
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">Noce</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lombo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trippa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Agnelo intero</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Agnellone intero</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>        
               <li>
                <a href="#">Aromi</a>
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">Preparato aromi in buste</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Preparato aromi in secchi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trippa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Agnelo intero</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Agnellone intero</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li> 
             <li>
                <a href="#">Uova</a>
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">Brick</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sfuse</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li> 
             <li>
                <a href="#">Natalizi</a>
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">Faraona</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Oca</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cappone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pollo disossato ripieno</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Zampone</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Cotechino</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stinco</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Anatra</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fagiano</a></li>  
                     <li><a href="#">Tacchino MIDI </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tacchino MINI </a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>


        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
    .sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
    margin:         0;
    padding:        0;
    list-style:     none;
}
.sf-menu {
    line-height:    1.0;
}
.sf-menu ul {
    position:       absolute;
    top:            -999em;
    width:          10em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */

}
.sf-menu ul li {
    width:          100%;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
    visibility:     inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
    float:          left;
    position:       relative;
}
.sf-menu a {
    display:        block;
    position:       relative;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
    left:           0;
    top:            2.5em; /* match top ul list item height */
    z-index:        99;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
    top:            -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
    left:           10em; /* match ul width */
    top:            0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
    top:            -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
    left:           10em; /* match ul width */
    top:            0;
}

/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.sf-menu {
    float:          left;
    margin-bottom:  1em;
}
.sf-menu a {
    border-left:    1px solid #fff;
    border-top:     1px solid #CFDEFF;
    padding:        .75em 1em;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
    color:          #13a;
}
.sf-menu li {
    background:     #BDD2FF;
}
.sf-menu li li {
    background:     #AABDE6;
}
.sf-menu li li li {
    background:     #9AAEDB;
}
.sf-menu li:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover,
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
    background:     #CFDEFF;
    outline:        0;
}

/*** arrows **/
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
    padding-right:  2.25em;
    min-width:      1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately */
}
.sf-sub-indicator {
    position:       absolute;
    display:        block;
    right:          .75em;
    top:            1.05em; /* IE6 only */
    width:          10px;
    height:         10px;
    text-indent:    -999em;
    overflow:       hidden;
    background:     url('../images/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
}
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
    top:            .8em;
    background-position: 0 -100px; /* use translucent arrow for modern browsers*/
}
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
    background-position: -10px -100px; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}

/* point right for anchors in subs */
.sf-menu ul .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  -10px 0; }
.sf-menu ul a > .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  0 0; }
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.sf-menu ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
    background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}
```

Help, thanks.

Comment: Cant make out what you want, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the `UL` under "Elaborati". You will probably have to tweak the values a bit to get it to look the way you want. You can make it even wider if you wish.

Then use:

```
ul.wide {
    width:300px;
}

ul.wide li  {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:90px;    
}

ul.wide a {
    height:90px; 
}
```